# Extract lines from text batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, text

I need to take a known number of lines from one text doc and put them in another. During or after this process I need to look at certain columns only. My idea:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "SKIP=21 TOKENS 1,3 DELIMS= " %%B IN (INPUT.TXT) DO ECHO %%B %%C > OUTPUT.TXT
```

When I try this I just get the last line of the file printed. I eventually want just lines 22-34, 1st and 3rd columns. Please keep simple.

Comment: What shell or platform are you using?

Comment: Can you use Windows PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `> OUTPUT.TXT` to `>> OUTPUT.TXT`

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counter=32-21
FOR /F "SKIP=21 TOKENS 1,3 DELIMS= " %%B IN (INPUT.TXT) DO (
 ECHO %%B %%C
 set /a counter=counter-1
 if !counter! == 0 (
    goto :break 
 ) 
)>> OUTPUT.TXT
:break
```

Like is posted you script will print all lines after 21th.To stop at 34 you'll need a break condition.
And as Kevin pointed you need appending redirection.

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to enclose entire construct in parens and redirect only once.

You can intentionally divide by zero and detect when to quit without any need for delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "cnt=13"
>output.txt (
  for /f "skip=21 tokens=1,3 delims= " %%B in (input.txt) do (
    echo(%%B %%C
    set /a "1/(cnt-=1)" 2>nul || goto :break
  )
)
:break
```

Or, if you get my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), then all you need is the following from the command line:

```
jrepl "^([^ ]*) [^ ]* ([^ ]*)" "$1 $2" /jmatch /jbegln "skip=(ln<22 || ln>34)" /f input.txt /o output.txt
```

The above assumes there is exactly one space between tokens. The regular expression can be modified if there may be multiple spaces between tokens.

You must use CALL JREPL if you use the command within a batch script.